# Firestore Query multiple child values gets FirebaseError: Invalid Query. A non-empty array is required for 'in' filters

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to query a collection and see if one the the child values (zipOne, zipTwo, zipThree) is equal to a zip code. Hoping someone could help. I keep on getting an error stating:

*FirebaseError: Invalid Query. A non-empty array is required for 'in' filters.*

Here are the children I am trying to query and check if my zip code matches any of them in 'servicing'.

[image: FireStore DB]

```
  import { getFirestore,collection,getDocs,doc,query,where,getDoc,setDoc,} from "firebase/firestore";

  const currentServicingZip = "33302";
  const q = query(
    collection(db, "business"),
    where("servicing.zipOne", "in", currentServicingZip),
    where("servicing.zipTwo", "in", currentServicingZip),
    where("servicing.zipThree", "in", currentServicingZip),
    );

  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, an `in` filter expects that you pass it an array of values. Even if you have only a single value, it has to be in an array. So:

```
collection(db, "business"),
  where("servicing.zipOne", "in", [currentServicingZip]),
  where("servicing.zipTwo", "in", [currentServicingZip]),
  where("servicing.zipThree", "in", [currentServicingZip]),
```

Two things to pay attention to here. First off, this is exactly the same as doing equality checks on those fields:

```
collection(db, "business"),
  where("servicing.zipOne", "==", currentServicingZip),
  where("servicing.zipTwo", "==", currentServicingZip),
  where("servicing.zipThree", "==", currentServicingZip),
```

Secondly, the above performs a logical AND query, so only returns documents where `zipOne`, `zipTwo` and `zipThree` all have the same value as `currentServicingZip`. Firestore currently doesn't support performing an OR condition across multiple fields in a document.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I understand now. I'll try restructuring my data and most likely make 'servicing' an array and use array-contains to search for my value.